# Does the particle 'の' change the meaning of this phrase?

Tags: particle-の

To say "Japanese language school" in Japanese, sentences 1 and 2 can be used? or they have different meanings because of the use of particle 'の' (sentence 2)?

> 1. [日本語]{にほんご}[学校]{がっこう} (nihongo gakkou)
> 2. [日本語]{にほんご}**の**[学校]{がっこう} (nihongo no gakkou)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct and both have the same meaning.

The only small difference would be that 「日本語{にほんご}**の**学校{がっこう}」 would look/sound a tiny bit more informal than 「日本語学校」.

The use of 「の」 often makes the phrase more informal.

「日本{にほん}の政府{せいふ}」 is more informal than 「日本政府」 though both mean "the Japanese government".